# Why does the do, while loop display the last number twice?

Tags: javascript, do-while

I have the following code:

```js
 var a = 0;
    
    do {
      console.log(a);
      a++;
    } while (a < 10);
```

And I was playing around with it to gain a better understanding of what is going on and I noticed that this will write the final number 9 twice. Can anyone explain this to me please?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Run it without console.log and you will see. Last "9" is a "result" of your script.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wazw9z7a/

Comment: Are you running this in a developer console or some other kind of REPL shell?

Comment: That's not what this code does. Run the snippet and see...

Comment: this does not output the last value twice to the console, the extra 9 is the result of the code as mentioned by Fif.

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the problem you're describing.

Comment: The code was written straight into the developer console in Chrome. What I didn't realise was that the last number was as Viplock described below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its working perfectly fine , the result is also perfect . the last number you see is because of "the console also displays the value of the last expression executed in the code you run there."
And this is something that expression returns . if some how there is a break statement in the loop the return will be undefined. and you will see only the console value .

or if you put the entire exp in a function you will not see this return . because the function will not return any thing like-

if you wanna check properly try using this

```
var fun=function(){var a = 0;

do {
  console.log(a);
  a++;
} while (a < 10);}
fun()
```

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: much better +1.

Comment: Thank you for that, great explanation!